# Add legend to x, y coordinates on the status bar

Tags: matplotlib

Does anyone know if it is possible to display the legend of the line my mouse is hovering over along with its values on the status bar (see figure below)? Since the line colors repeat, I cannot identify which data series I'm looking at.
I tried playing with the Axes.format_coord method with no luck.

Thank you.
[image: Multiple lines graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could employ [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to update the status bar while hovering.

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np

def show_in_toolbar(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(sel.annotation.get_text().replace("\n", "; "))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 4))
for i in range(1, 21):
    ax.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), label=f'Curve {i}')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1), loc='upper left', ncol=2)
# erase the message when not hovering over a curve
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", lambda event: fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message(""))
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
# call show_in_toolbar while hovering over a curve
cursor.connect("add", show_in_toolbar)
ax.margins(x=0.01)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors update toolbar]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I wanted!!