# How to display all the informations of a scatterplot dot with pick event when using Seaborn and facet-grid

Tags: dataframe, seaborn, mouseevent, scatter-plot, facet-grid

I have a Pandas database (below I am creating a random database to mimic mine).

I use Seaborn, facet-grid and scatterplot to plot the data the way I want : **Epsilon1** as a function of **no**, I distinguish the data from the sub categories **A** and **B** using different subplots and colors. This part of the code works correctly.

Then I want that the user can click on any dot in order to display in the IPython console and in the status bar of the Matplotlib figure (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750332/change-format-of-coordinate-text-in-status-bar)) all the informations about this dot : that is to say all the values of the corresponding dataframe row: something like:
'no':5, 'Date':1997-12-15 03:50:41, 'A':A6, 'B':B4, 'Epsilon1':0.670635, 'Epsilon2':0.756461, 'Epsilon3':0.530825

I have made first tests using onpick event (not shown here) but all were unsuccessful.
Actually I can't get by with the function onpick(event) because I do not understand why print(event.ind) gives me a list of integers...

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns
import random

# size of the database
n = 1000

nA = 6
nB = 5

no = np.arange(n)
date = np.random.randint(1e9, size=n).astype('datetime64[s]')
A = [''.join(['A',str(random.randint(1, nA))]) for j in range(n)]
B = [''.join(['B',str(random.randint(1, nB))]) for j in range(n)]
Epsilon1 = np.random.random_sample((n,))
Epsilon2 = np.random.random_sample((n,))
Epsilon3 = np.random.random_sample((n,))

data = pd.DataFrame({'no':no,
                     'Date':date,
                     'A':A,
                     'B':B,
                     'Epsilon1':Epsilon1,
                     'Epsilon2':Epsilon2,
                     'Epsilon3':Epsilon3})

def onpick(event):

    print(event.ind)

def plot_Epsilon1_seaborn():
    
    sns.set_theme()
    
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, 
                      col="A", 
                      col_wrap=4,
                      hue='B',
                      hue_order=data['B'].sort_values().drop_duplicates().to_list(),
                      palette="viridis", 
                      col_order=data['A'].sort_values().drop_duplicates().to_list()) 
    g.map(sns.scatterplot,
          'no',
          'Epsilon1',
          picker=True)
    
    g.add_legend()
    
    g.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    plot_Epsilon1_seaborn()
```

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337574/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes. I'm also currently developping a solution with mplcursors. Once found, I will post it on this page. However, here, I am rather looking for a solution which displays the informations in the IPython console and in the status bar of the Matplotlib figure.

Comment: See [Add legend to x, y coordinates on the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643653/add-legend-to-x-y-coordinates-on-the-status-bar) about how you can update the status bar with mplcursors instead of showing a popup. Anyway, you can't rely on seaborn's automatic sectioning of the data, you'll need your own splitting of the dataframe.  Also, you seem to want to put a lot more information into the status bar than what normally fits there (this also depends on the window size).

Comment: Using only Matplotlib, I have developed another code that plots the points of database. The data is plotted on several figures and subplots, and so is now more readable and I am closer to the point I want to reach: the user by putting the cursor over a point has access to all the information of the point, in particular the datetime. However, I have problem with datetime format. I posted this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75398867/changing-the-format-of-coordinate-text-with-datetime-in-status-bar-of-a-matplo)